# Information Bar appears in IE8 while downloading

Tags: internet-explorer-8, google-docs, information-bar

I have an application in which there are options to Export the document in Word/PDF format. We do a form submit to post the HTML and send it to the server for conversion. In the back-end the servlet writes it back to client after setting a contentType. The Information Bar appears during the first download only.

I cannot recommend users to reduce their Browser Security levels. Hence i need a solution to by-pass this alert. I saw that Google Docs has handled this. Does anyone have an idea about what needs to be done ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following JQuery code:

```
$.download = function(url, data, method){
    //url and data options required
    if( url && data ){ 
        //data can be string of parameters or array/object
        data = typeof data == 'string' ? data : $.param(data);
        //split params into form inputs
        var inputs = '';
        $.each(data.split('&'), function(){ 
            var pair = this.split('=');
            inputs+='<input type="hidden" name="'+ pair[0] +'" value="'+ pair[1] +'" />'; 
        });
        //send request
        $('<form action="'+ url +'" method="'+ (method||'post') +'">'+inputs+'</form>')
        .appendTo('body').submit().remove();
    };
};
```

And each time download should be initiated, I'm firing

```
$.download(options);
```

Server response is with proper content-type headers (e.g. Word).

Maybe you have forgotten to remove submitted form from the DOM?

Comment: Hi BasTaller, i tried out the solution suggested by you. But still i get the Information Bar during first download...